# How to make Emacs "forget" code evaluated in scratch buffer?

Tags: scratch-buffer

I have a function named `my-func` in my `init.el`.  I copy this function to the `scratch` buffer, make some changes to it and evaluate it with `C - j`. I then delete the code in the `scratch` buffer and then call `my-func`, but it executes the `scratch` version, not the `init.el` version.

How can I make Emacs forget code evaluated in the `scratch` buffer ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just redefine the function with its original definition again.

You'll probably find this article very helpful:
https://masteringemacs.org/article/evaluating-elisp-emacs

You can't 'undo' lisp evaluation like you can undo text editing -- Emacs isn't keeping a history of all previous states of the lisp interpreter (it couldn't do so -- the idea just isn't practical).  Maintaining a history of versions of named functions *would* be possible, but Emacs doesn't do that.

If you want to experiment with elisp in a safe environment, simply start a separate instance of Emacs.